# How to do radial collections querying in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, computational-geometry

I have lots of points (with `.X` and `.Y` coordinates) in a 2d space For example a [KDTree](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Collections_KDTree_1.htm) or some other `IEnumerable<AnyXYPointImpl>` collection. I want to do query that is not square but Circle\Radius based:

[image]

What I want is simple: having a point `P`, direction `D` and half angle `a` we want to get all points in the  collection area covered by a sector formed by them.

So how to do such radial collections querying in C# with LINQ?

Comment: I'd separate this into two parts: 1) Non-LINQ - for a single point, can you tell whether it should be in the collection? 2) Use the condition you've created in the first step in a `Where` call.

Comment: This is essentially Collision Detection between a point and a sector.  I see you have some maximum distance D.  If performance is a concern when using a large number of points, it would be more efficient to compute the bounding box of the sector, and filter all points against the bounding box using a KDTree.  Any LINQ query against an IEnumerable will be, at best, linear O(n) performance, whereas searches against a KDTree will be O(log n).

Comment: @Wyck: yep - [`GetNodesInsideRegion`](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Collections_KDTree_1.htm) and then use [@aleha answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600712/1973207).

Comment: @DuckQueen, aleha's answer is a great, but technically it doesn't use LINQ.  (I don't think the `Any` call counts.)  It returns an IEnumerable from scratch using a loop.  A LINQ solution would provide a predicate to a `where` clause, ideally with expressions that that result could potentially be transformed to a server-side query.  Is LINQ really a requirement for you?  (I don't think it should be, for performance reasons I already mentioned.  I'm just trying to clarify your question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rWx75x):

Example usage:

```
var field = new List<Vector2>() {
            new Vector2(-1,1),  new Vector2(1,1), 
            new Vector2(-1,-1), new Vector2(1,-1)
        };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", field.IsInSector(new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(2,2), 45.0)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", field.IsInSector(new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(2,-2), 45.0)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", field.IsInSector(new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(2,0), 90.0)));
```

Main logic to check point is it in sector via IEnumerable extension:

```
public static class Extenctions {
    public static IEnumerable<IXYPoint> IsInSector(this IEnumerable<IXYPoint> source, Vector2 pointToCheck, Vector2 direction, double halfAngle)
    {
        if(!source.Any() || pointToCheck == null || halfAngle <= 0)
            return new IXYPoint[0];

        var dirVector = new Vector2() {
            X = direction.X - pointToCheck.X,
            Y = direction.Y - pointToCheck.Y
        };

        var radius = Distance(direction, pointToCheck);
        var result = new List<IXYPoint>();

        foreach(var p in source)
        {
            if(Distance(p, pointToCheck) > radius){ // check is point in circle
                continue;
            }


            if(IsPointInSector(dirVector, p, halfAngle)) // main check 
                result.Add(p);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static double Distance(IXYPoint from, IXYPoint to)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(to.X - from.X,2) + Math.Pow(from.Y-to.Y,2));
    }

    private static bool IsPointInSector(IXYPoint directionVector, IXYPoint pointToCheck, double halfAngle)
    {
        var rq0 = Math.Pow(directionVector.X,2) + Math.Pow(directionVector.Y,2);
        var rq = Math.Pow(pointToCheck.X,2) + Math.Pow(pointToCheck.Y,2);
        return rq0 >= rq && (directionVector.X*pointToCheck.X + directionVector.Y*pointToCheck.Y)/Math.Sqrt(rq0*rq) >= Math.Cos(halfAngle/180.0*Math.PI);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a non-LINQ solution.

```
    var filteredPoints = new List<Point2D>();

    foreach (var point in points)
        if (point.IsInSector(origin, d, a))
            filteredPoints.Add(point);
```